# Plugin for gallery with thumbnails?

Tags: plugins, gallery

Does anyone know of a galley plug-in which would have this kind of functionality?

```
-------------------------------------------
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |    <-image shows whatever thumbnail is clicked
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
-------------------------------------------
-----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
|   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |    <-thumbnails
|   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |
-----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
```

Ideally, it would allow separate galleries on each page. And load the pictures when you click a thumbnail, without reloading the whole page.

Comment: using WP's built-in gallery system (attachments) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photospace http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photospace/

If you want to just use jquery I recommend http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/  galleriffic.

Comment: photospace seems to be a good choice for now. i will investigate further

Answer (score 1):

If you use Flickr, you can use the [Flickr Photo Album](http://tantannoodles.com/toolkit/photo-album/) plugin to display your Flickr photos on your WP site.

[Have a look at my gallery](http://grantpalin.com/gallery/). This is how I set it up, but it is **very** configurable, so you can customize the layout to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at WP Slideshow Gallery - http://wpgallery.tribulant.net